# In interviews, how do I address being let go for using my sick/vacation days?

Tags: interviewing

This is in the state of Texas, which I believe is an at-will state. The company gives 10 sick days, plus 10 vacation days. Pretty awesome.

My wife works about 4 months out of the year(Jan-April). During that time, if our daughter is sick/has appointments or anything like that, I use my days to take care of her. Not to mention if I get sick, or other emergency arises, I use my days.

In the last two years, I've used about 8-9 days of sick and 8-9 days of vacation by June/July. After this happened the first time, I was talked to by the new project manager because there was a concern I may need to take unpaid time off, and that would affect insurance and other benefits and such. I've never, in fact, used more than the days allotted.

Now, this year, it occurred again. This time, I explained to my project manager the reasoning behind it, and she seemed okay with this. My project lead has never had a problem with my taking the days, nor has he ever had a problem with my work. He always let me know I was doing good, and the only time I missed a deadline was when the requirements changed 2 days before the deadline.

All that said, the project manager let me go with the claim that it was a "pattern of unsatisfactory work performance." I guess my question is, when the inevitable question of "What caused you to leave your last position?" comes up, how best can I frame this? I obviously don't want to lie to a potential employer, but I also want to get ahead of my former employer saying I was fired for unsatisfactory work performance, when in actuality, my work performance was never in question.

Comment: So you obeyed company leave policy, and the quality of your work was satisfactory, and you were fired for seemingly contradictory reasons.  Either we're not getting the whole picture, or you were fired unfairly and this borders on a legal issue.

Comment: You state that your work, as rated by your *lead* was good.  What was the opinion of the project *manager*?

Comment: I think you need to have a conversation with a labor type lawyer.

Comment: @MikeQ Sadly there are plenty of employers who give "generous" time off but actively discourage people from taking it, especially when it's in the form of a split system. This is not at all surprising or rare.

Comment: @Lilienthal Yes, certainly. What I meant was, perhaps an anti-discrimination law/policy exists to prevent termination based on illness, family needs, etc. If so, then I suspect the company tried to circumvent it, which seems objectively unfair (if not legally questionable). But this doesn't answer OP's question, so I leave it as a comment instead.

Comment: @MikeQ unfair, and commonly done.

Comment: @MikeQ: I assure you, this is the whole picture, at least from my side of the frame. I do understand that as a PM, she may have a different view, but that has never been made clear to me outside of what I've already stated.

Comment: Hmm, why exactly are we closing this as legal? OP isn't asking a legal question at all but is just asking how to phrase this when it comes up in an interview. That's a workplace issue and not a legal one.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand what a "sick day" is, but it seems to me like it is distinct from, *and therefore not*, a vacation day.  It is not just "more vacation days with a different name".  If you are not sick and not taking a vacation or unpaid day, you must show up.  Not doing so is fraud. That's what I thought!

Comment: @Harper: Some companies offer a secondary set of PTO that is dubbed "sick days". These are sometimes paid, and meant for the purposes of being taken due to self or immediate family sickness. The difference between "sick" and "vacation" is that in some cases, "vacation" can roll over or be paid for at the end of the year, where as "sick" does neither of those.

Comment: I can see the issue being a problem, you say that this only occurs during 4 months (approximately 16 weeks), but you take 16-18 days off during those weeks, probably with very short or no notice. That means you are taking off at least 1 day per week, sometimes 2. While within your days, it still seems excessive (and I have kids so I know how it goes, but that seems like a lot, unless your child has a chronic illness). I would be honest with your next employer and attempt to find other ways to have your child cared for (personal sitter, family, etc).

Comment: @MyCodeSucks Did you consider that maybe the fired you because your code sucks? I mean, I know exactly two things about you: your name is "My Code Sucks" and you got fired. Just putting two and two together here.

Comment: What does your contract say about the definition of a sick day? Does it specify that a sick day is only to be used when you yourself are too sick to come to work, sit in a chair, and write code? If your daughter has to go to the dentist and you use an entire sick day for that, does your contract define that as OK?

Comment: @MikeQ Nobody wrote anything about *getting fired*

Comment: Do you have any **explicit** indication that it was your use of sick days that got you fired? Because I'm not seeing any specific evidence for that assumption.

Comment: @Kaz: The indication is that's exactly what I was told.

Answer (score 11):

> When the inevitable question of "What caused you to leave your last position?" comes up, how best can I frame this?

Say something like the following:

> I was let go because I used the PTO that [I negotiated as // was] part of my benefits package. They considered actually using those days to be a performance issue.

Good managers will be somewhat incredulous. Most interviewers will ask to elaborate. If they do you can point out some of the following:

- you never missed a deadline (changing requirements void deadlines)
- your performance was never questioned
- you had great performance reviews (if true of course)
- when you asked your PM if it was okay to use your PTO he agreed
- you never even used all the days you were given

The reason you should call it PTO is that you usually want to avoid making any reference to health problems and mentioning "sick days" qualifies. It can sometimes affect an interviewer's impression of you, even subconsciously. [PTO can be used as a generic term these days,](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/93001/is-generic-pto-without-sick-days-time-normal-in-the-us/93002#93002) but of course don't lie or avoid mentioning sick days at all costs, it's really not that big of a deal. You may want to throw in that you used it to care for a sick child to dispel any notions that you've got a chronic health issue.

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately, many organizations include sick leave in their basic compensation package, but then expect it to be used only under dire conditions.  Also, some expect vacation time (which is earned, not given BTW), to be used only in week increments, not one day at a time.  The trouble is, few of them are straight forward and actually tell you these things, so you situation is not that unusual.

As an interviewer, I would likely accept an explanation along the lines of "I needed time off for family circumstances which I felt took priority.  Management disagreed and had not explained their policy about taking time off for such reasons and let me go."  If the company you are applying to has the same attitude, it will disqualify you, and you can move of to someone else who has a better attitude for a healthy home life.

Comment: I would say that "management did not explain their unwritten policy..."